# How to list all endpoints in an Express application using Node.js, like "Loopback explorer"

Tags: node.js, express, routes, loopback

I have a expressjs API, I am looking for a package to list all of my endpoints with routes, and schema example.

I have found similar thing [pathfider-ui](https://github.com/smlee/pathfinder-ui). It is good but it does not show the json schema structure of collections like loopback does.

So I am looking for another one which should include the schema json file, path/endPoints. In addition, each schema routes should be separated.
For example
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopback uses [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) under the hood. It might be the tool that you're looking for

[Here's an article by M Herman](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/05/26/swagger-and-nodejs/#.Wd3URRO0NTY) on how to use Swagger with Express

Comment: Oh and this link too from Scotch IO: https://scotch.io/tutorials/speed-up-your-restful-api-development-in-node-js-with-swagger

Comment: This is good, but the only problem is that you have to write the schema again under @swagger which is time consuming.